# Is it possible to utilize cloud build to containerize a JAR already built?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

At my company, a shared upstream JAR is provided to us from a development team by way of storing in Artifactory. I am wanting to utilize Cloud Build to grab this JAR from artifactory, and containerize, upload image to Artifact Registry, and deploy it to GKE. I have proven out the last two steps: containerize, upload to Artifact Registry, and deploy to a GKE cluster however this only works when using the Cloud CLI locally in a directory where my JAR and Dockerfile already exist.

Everywhere in documentation I am only seeing references to connecting to GitHub/BitBucket repos where the source code as hosted, and *then* it creates the JAR.

Is it possible to utilize the functionality of Cloud Build to look for a new JAR in Artifactory, and build the container from there?

Comment: in our company the jar shared in artifactory is in form of maven repo artifacts, and we can easily use maven to pull them, it is just a private maven registry.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, yes, this should be possible; "in principle" because I've not tried to do this.

However, Cloud Build is best considered to be a general-purpose, serial pipeline that allows you to apply functions (containers) to a set of inputs. Side-effects are ubiquitous, primarily through containers making calls to other services|APIs.

If I understand correctly, your mean JFrog [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Artifactory).

You will need credentials to access JFrog and some mechanism to `pull` from the repo. This should be straightforward to implement and deploy as a container (if someone hasn't provided this functionality already).

###### Update

[Integrating Google Cloud Build with JFrog Artifactory](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/integrating-google-cloud-build-with-jfrog-artifactory). it's dated (2018) but appears to outline the workflow that you need.

There's also a [`jfrog`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/jfrog) builder in the [`gcloud-builders-community`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community); a repo that includes a set of open-source (?) builders (containers) written by 3rd-party developers that work with Cloud Build.